# How to apply background color to buttons using css in asp.net?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have an asp.net web form and I want to set the same background color to all the buttons in the form using CSS.This is what I have tried:

CSS:

```
body 
{
background-color:#336699;
}

.button 
{  
   background-color: #336699;   
   color: white;  
}

.button:hover 
{   
   background-color: White;
   color :#336699 
}
```

Page Source:

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<link href="../Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Button Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Height="40px" 
                            OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" 
Visible="False"     Width="90px" />
```

The background color for the body is applied successfully,but for buttons this code is not working.Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the buttons' markup

Comment: Why is the button not visible?

Comment: The button doesn't seem to have the "button" class applied? Try adding `CssClass="button"` to the `<asp:Button>` tag?

Comment: That's the mistake I made, rather silly one.Thanks @xec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note how your stylesheet declares styles. This:

```
body
```

is a set of styles to be applied to a tag `body`. However this:

```
.button
.button:hover
```

is a class, it will be applied only to those elements which have this class declared. SO you need to make sure the button has this class:

```
<asp:Button ... CssClass="button"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Css Class selector to your button

```
<asp:Button CssClass="buttonClass" ID="btnSave" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Height="40px"                                 OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" Visible="False" Width="90px"  />
```

then add design your class in your style

```
.buttonClass
{
   background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here might be a fix to `<input type="button" class="button">` - 
but if there is, I don't know it.

```
.button 
{
   background-color: #E3E1B8; 
   padding: 2px 4px;
   font: 13px sans-serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-color: #aaa #444 #444 #aaa;
   color: #000
}
```